# Signing a string with RSA private key on .NET?

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, der

```
byte[] plaintext = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AAAAAAAAAAAAA");

TextReader trCer = new StreamReader(@"AA.key"); //key in PEM format

PemReader rdCer = new PemReader(trCer);

AsymmetricCipherKeyPair o = rdCer.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;

ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("MD5WithRSAEncryption");

sig.Init(true, o.Private);

sig.BlockUpdate(plaintext,0,plaintext.Length);

Byte[] signature  = sig.GenerateSignature();

string signatureHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

Console.WriteLine(signatureHeader);
```

How I can use a key in DER format?
I'm using the library BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll

`

Comment: "DER format" is not enough information. DER is applicable for any structure described using ASN.1.

Comment: Did you find a way to read keys in DER format?

Comment: Also see [Signing and verifying signatures with RSA C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8437288/608639), [how to sign bytes using my own rsa private key using rs256 algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25909044/608639), [Signing data with private key in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31828420/608639), [How can I sign a file using RSA and SHA256 with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7444586/608639), [Signing a string with RSA private key on .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3169829/608639), etc.

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269406/read-der-private-key-in-c-sharp-using-bouncycastle

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `der` file to `pem` file using `OpenSsl`:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

And then generate sign from `pem` using `BountyCastle` like this:

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var privateKey = new StringBuilder();
                privateKey.AppendLine("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");
                privateKey.AppendLine(_config.Value.PrivateKey);
                privateKey.AppendLine("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----");

                var pem = new PemReader(new StringReader(privateKey.ToString()));
                var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pem.ReadObject();
                var privateKeyParameters = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;
                var rsaParameters = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKeyParameters);

                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
                var sign = rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), new HashAlgorithmName("SHA1"),
                    RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(sign);
            }
```

Above snipped code use private key as a string and I wrap it into pem format.

Comment: You might want to add a note that the `DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters` is provided by [BouncyCastle](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/security/DotNetUtilities.cs), because it does not come with .NET framework as such.

Comment: Yes you are right but in question was mentioned ``BountyCastle``

Comment: Oh didn't see that. Thanks for pointing out. Probably worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: @Christian.K  Answer updated and mentioned ``BountryCastle``. Thanks