# signing with x509certificate that has signature algorithm sha256

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sign a file using RSA and SHA256 with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444586/how-can-i-sign-a-file-using-rsa-and-sha256-with-net)

I am trying to sign a PDF document with a x509certificate, which has signature algorithm sha256. I have written the following code for this.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaCSP.FromXmlString(cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
signature = rsaCSP.SignData(dataToBeSigned, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

which yields into an exception saying "Key not valid for specified state"

Then I have made an edit like the following:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
signature = rsaCSP.SignData(dataToBeSigned, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

This yields into an exception saying "Invalid algorithm specified"

I have no clue for the errors, can anyone help me to get out from this deadlock please ?

Comment: Which line throws the excetpion in the first case?

Comment: 2nd line rsaCSP.FromXmlString(cert.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2008/08/25/using-rsacryptoserviceprovider-for-rsa-sha256-signatures.aspx - and some of the duplicate questions which I hadn't noticed before.