# How can I (properly) verify a file using RSA and SHA256 with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, hash, rsa, digital-signature

I was following [this great tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c.aspx?PageIndex=1) on digitally signing/verifying data with .NET. I modified that example code to use SHA256 and hit the "Invalid algorithm specified" exception, which led me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444586/how-can-i-sign-a-file-using-rsa-and-sha256-with-net) about signing data with SHA256 in .NET 4.0.

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637121) from that post helped me figure out how to properly generate the digital signature by explicitly loading a SHA256-capable crypto provider without relying on an exportable private key (see the code towards the bottom of the following method where the **RSACryptoServiceProvider** is constructed):

```
static string mKeyContainerName;

static byte[] SignText(string text, string publicCertPath)
{
    // Access Personal (MY) certificate store of current user
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    // Load the certificate we'll use to verify the signature from a file.
    X509Certificate2 publicCert = new X509Certificate2(publicCertPath);
    publicCert.Verify();
    string publicHash = publicCert.GetCertHashString();

    // Find the certificate we'll use to sign
    X509Certificate2 privateCert = null;
    foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
    {
            if(cert.GetCertHashString() == publicHash)
            {
                    // We found it. Get its associated private key
                    privateCert = cert;
                    break;
            }
    }
    store.Close();

    if(privateCert == null)
    {
            throw new Exception("No valid private cert was found");
    }

    // Hash the string
    UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(text);
    SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);

    // The basic crypto provider only supports SHA-1.
    // Force Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider which supports SHA-256.
    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCert.PrivateKey;
    var enhCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().CspKeyContainerInfo;
    mKeyContainerName = csp.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
    var cspparams = new CspParameters
    (
            enhCsp.ProviderType, enhCsp.ProviderName, mKeyContainerName
    );
    csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);

    // Sign the hash
    return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
}
```

It may be worth noting that I am using a self-signed cert from makecert.exe. According to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11223973) in that same post, these problems wouldn't occur if I included the proper **-sp** or **-sy** flags in makercert.exe. However, even after specifying either of these flags (currently using **-sy 24**) I still have to perform the workaround.

This implementation differs slightly from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475985) in that post (again, as our private key is not exportable). But that answer does indicate that the verification can be done without explicitly loading a SHA256-capable crypto provider. Thus, I should have been able to do this before returning in the method above:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCert.PrivateKey;
var enhCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().CspKeyContainerInfo;
mKeyContainerName = csp.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
var cspparams = new CspParameters
(
    enhCsp.ProviderType, enhCsp.ProviderName, mKeyContainerName
);
csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);

// Sign the hash
byte[] signature = csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));

// Test to verify the signed hash with public cert
csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)publicCert.PublicKey.Key;
if (!csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature))
    throw new CryptographicException();

return signature;
```

However, this won't verify (BTW, I've tried both **SignData/VerifyData** and **SignHash/VerifyHash**). The only way I can get it to verify is if I again explicitly load a SHA256-capable crypto provider. Unfortunately, the **KeyContainerName** member of the **CspKeyContainerInfo** constructed from a public certificate is always null. Thus, the only way I can get the data to verify is if I cache (or hard-code) the private key's KeyContainerName. Hence the reason for the **mKeyContainerName** field in the above method and snippet below:

```
// Test to verify the signed hash with public cert
csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)publicCert.PublicKey.Key;
enhCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().CspKeyContainerInfo;
cspparams = new CspParameters
(
    enhCsp.ProviderType, enhCsp.ProviderName, mKeyContainerName
);
csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);
if (!csp.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), signature))
    throw new CryptographicException();
```

This does verify, but I don't like having to hard-code the private key's **KeyContainerName**. The private key won't be available on the machine that is doing the verification.

Does anyone know of a better way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on my own answer quite by accident. Turns out using a self-signed cert created with makecert.exe is the culprit here. If I use a cert created with OpenSSL or a commercial cert, I no longer have to explicitly load a SHA256-capable crypto provider. Thus I don't have to hard code the container name in the CspParameters object used to instantiate the RSACryptoServiceProvider. This signing code now works as expected:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateCert.PrivateKey;
// Sign the hash
byte[] signature = csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
```

The same is true on the verify side:

```
// Test to verify the signed hash with public cert
csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)publicCert.PublicKey.Key;
```

I never found out what was different about the cert generated by makecert.exe, but it was not important for me as we are signing with a commercial cert now.