# Get certificate KeyContainerName and other attributes

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

I am trying to sign XML with a custom generated certificate which is acessible via this code

```
private void buttonSelectCertificate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CertStoreLocation = (StoreLocation)cboStoreLocation.SelectedItem;
   CertStoreName = (StoreName)cboStoreName.SelectedItem;
   X509Store store = new X509Store(CertStoreName, CertStoreLocation);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate",  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
}
```

What I cannot get how to use properly `X509Certificate2Collection scollection` 
in order to fill out following  properties.

Also I am not getting following idea:

If certificate is stored here `My = 5`   then have I use 
`CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore` ?

How can I get the `KeyContainerName` from `X509Certificate2Collection scollection`?

And finally maybe I am completely wrong in the way to get certificate attributes I need in order to populate `CspParameters` class, any clue?

Thank you for help!

```
// Get the key pair from the key store.
CspParameters parms = new CspParameters(1);         // PROV_RSA_FULL
parms.Flags = ??? CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;  // Use Machine store
parms.KeyContainerName = ???;               // 
parms.KeyNumber = 2;                                // AT_SIGNATURE
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parms);
```

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/q/7444586/2779990; you may also be able to do something like var x = scollection[0] as X509Certificate2 (forgive my code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the answer

```
private void buttonSelectCertificate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CertStoreLocation = (StoreLocation)cboStoreLocation.SelectedItem;
   CertStoreName = (StoreName)cboStoreName.SelectedItem;
   X509Store store = new X509Store(CertStoreName, CertStoreLocation);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, "Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate",  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);


  foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in scollection)
            {

                var rsa = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
                if (rsa == null) continue; // not smart card cert again

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName))
                {
                    // This is how we can get it! :)  
                    var keyContainerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName;
                }
            }
}
```

And also we have use normally  `CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore`

```
CspParameters parms = new CspParameters(1);         // PROV_RSA_FULL
parms.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;  // Use Machine store
```