# Validate the signature of a response from a web service with .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, xml-signature

I want to validate a signature with c# .net, I already have the Key.cert:

**Response SOAP**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.abcdefg.com/ServicioSub/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse11:SignatureConfirmation
            xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" Value="JHy/t5+j4eRFAP+MVKt9r6V7EDK1LPmMT12OhIQewyhQPWu5Z1A5eMkPD9O0IUZgQqwxId7FmAuGozkplPQbB7DmLnpBra1iwDosDFFUUO11x43wQNu9O1s9xlaxp5AQjSFukoLQzP1bYAmGEjxNLBwv7HfUblXhYf4S4J1AqzJT73EaxJgJpx0TFeICJkUmfaHr8DQMvGhd+C+1jAsUcfuAl/J0Eswt8MPq/LIjhg8gZA8OZu6fP1LJMDAJH+/jU8yIi2WlSq7Qi2R4YsyuDFaQkbSa6fVp8XXF9M3Wof6/Pcw2yeIE8a0Ts8YG5/FcxmgYsyJEA6p1iJikrj/Z6Q==" wsu:Id="b5e7634jc2d428dd4t36e94b9a690037" />
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="IDke77a718-9fg7-a713-69ef-klb18r337b69">
            <ns1:ResponseCall>
                <date>2023-10-18T12:26:34+02:00</date>
                <result>
                    <codigo>OK</codigo>
                    <descripcion>Correct result</descripcion>
                </result>
                <id_sub>SUG-AA-2023-000421</id_sub>
                <anuncio_1>[DATA]</anuncio_1>
                <anuncio_1>[DATA]</anuncio_1>
                <anuncio_3>[DATA]</anuncio_3>
                <anuncio_4>[DATA]</anuncio_4>
                <estado>PT</estado>
                <url_sub>[DATA]</url_sub>
            </ns1:ResponseCall>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please, can someone help me find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660912/7450780)

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k Thanks, but it's not the same case.

Comment: What have you come up with? And isn't working as you expect?

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k In the case that you have indicated, they sign some data and verify it, in my case it is a response from a WS that is signed. The purpose of my objective is to verify if the signature is appropriate or not, through the public key that I have. I hope I have explained clearly what I need. Thanks!!

Comment: So why not leverage what they are doing with the verification of the signature and apply it to your case?

Comment: I have applied it but it does not work in my case, I have checked the entire response to validate the signature and it does not work, "Value" in the header does not work either. I have done several tests and tests and I still can't verify it :(

Comment: "I have applied it but it does not work in my case, I have checked the entire response to validate the signature and it does not work" ..Does the `VerifyData` return false or  an exception is thrown?

Comment: It returns false, but I'm sure it's signed correctly. What I want is to validate the signature of the response with the public key that I have. FYI, the header has "Value" and "wsu:Id". The value that "wsu:Id" has is the MD5 of the "Value". But how to validate or describe the "Value"...no idea.

Comment: "I'm sure it's signed correctly" Prove the signature is indeed  right ! by doing the signing yourself to determine  you get the same  signature, if `VerifyData` is returning false then something is off could be different public key, different private key, different data between what's being verified and what data was signed. A number of things could be off here, I would advise you to first sign with the private key does result match signature coming in header?