# How to sign url in .net for google cloud storage

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net, google-cloud-storage

I want to know that how to generate signurl using google cloud storage classes in .net

I have created string as per the requirement

```
GET


1388534400
/bucket/objectname
```

but I now want to sign this url with p12 key and then want to make it url friendly

This library doesn't show specific function for it -> https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/csharp/latest/annotated.html

So, basically I need .net alternate of Google_Signer_P12 class of php

```
$signer = new Google_Signer_P12(file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'."final.p12"), "notasecret");
$signature = $signer->sign($to_sign);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my google signer code, One can make it more dynamic as per their needs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace HHAFSGoogle
{
    static class GoogleSigner
    {
        private static string hashAlgo = "SHA256";
        public static string ServiceAccountEmail
        {
            get
            {
                return "XXXXXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            }
        }

        public static string GoogleSecreat
        {
            get
            {
                return "notasecret";
            }
        }

        public static string GoogleBucketDir
        {
            get
            {
                return "MyBucketDirectory";
            }
        }

        public static string GoogleBucketName
        {
            get
            {
                return "MyBucket";
            }
        }

        public static string CertiFilelocation
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("p12file.p12");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get URL signature
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="base64EncryptedData"></param>
        /// <param name="certiFilelocation"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetSignature(string base64EncryptedData, string certiFilelocation)
        {
            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certiFilelocation, GoogleSecreat, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;

            RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            privateKey1.ImportParameters(csp.ExportParameters(true));

            csp.ImportParameters(privateKey1.ExportParameters(true));

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64EncryptedData.Replace("\r", ""));

            byte[] signature = privateKey1.SignData(data, hashAlgo);

            bool isValid = privateKey1.VerifyData(data, hashAlgo, signature);

            if (isValid)
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get signed URL by Signature
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="content_type"></param>
        /// <param name="duration"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetSignedURL(string fileName, string method = "GET", string content_type = "", int duration = 10)
        {
            TimeSpan span = (DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
            var expires = Math.Round(span.TotalSeconds, 0);

            // Encode filename, so URL characters like %20 for space could be handled properly in signature
            fileName = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName);

            // Generate a string to sign
            StringBuilder sbFileParam = new StringBuilder();
            sbFileParam.AppendLine(method);  //Could be GET, PUT, DELETE, POST
            //  /* Content-MD5 */ "\n" .
            sbFileParam.AppendLine();
            sbFileParam.AppendLine(content_type);   // Type of content you would upload e.g. image/jpeg
            sbFileParam.AppendLine(expires.ToString());     // Time when link should expire and shouldn't work longer
            sbFileParam.Append("/" + GoogleBucketName + "/" + fileName);

            var signature = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(GetSignature(sbFileParam.ToString(), CertiFilelocation));

            return ("https://storage.googleapis.com/MyBucket/" + fileName +
                        "?response-content-disposition=attachment;&GoogleAccessId=" + ServiceAccountEmail +
                        "&Expires=" + expires + "&Signature=" + signature);
        }
    }
}
```

and to download file call above class to get signed url

```
GoogleSigner.GetSignedURL(bucketFileName)
```

and to upload file call above class to get signed url for upload url

```
GoogleSigner.GetSignedURL(fileName, "PUT", type);
```

Comment: What value should go in the `GoogleSecreat`? I'm getting an exception when I try to create the certificate

Comment: Which code line exactly you are talking about?, If you are talking about 'notasecret' string than put it as it is i.e. 'notasecret'

Answer (score 8):

Now there is a [UrlSigner](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner.html) in the pre-release package [Google.Cloud.Storage.V1](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/index.html) that can be used to  to provide read-only access to existing objects:

```
// Create a signed URL which can be used to get a specific object for one hour.
UrlSigner urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountCredential(credential);
string url = urlSigner.Sign(
    bucketName,
    objectName,
    TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    HttpMethod.Get);
```

Or write-only access to put specific object content into a bucket:

```
// Create a signed URL which allows the requester to PUT data with the text/plain content-type.
UrlSigner urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountCredential(credential);
var destination = "places/world.txt";
string url = urlSigner.Sign(
    bucketName,
    destination,
    TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
    HttpMethod.Put,
    contentHeaders: new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
        { "Content-Type", new[] { "text/plain" } }
    });

// Upload the content into the bucket using the signed URL.
string source = "world.txt";

ByteArrayContent content;
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(source))
{
    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    content = new ByteArrayContent(data)
    {
        Headers = { ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain") }
    };
}

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know the question was for P12, but Google lead me here when I was looking to do this for the newer, preferred JSON method.  I pieced this together with other samples and sites I found.  Hope this help save some time.

```
    public string GetSignedURL()
    {
        var myObj = "theObject";
        var scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write" };
        var myBucket = "theBucket";
        ServiceAccountCredential cred;

        using ( var stream = new FileStream(@"\path to\private-key.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) )
        {
            cred = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                   .CreateScoped(scopes)
                                   .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
        }

        var urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountCredential(cred);

        return urlSigner.Sign(myBucket, myObj, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), HttpMethod.Get);
    }
```

A list of Scopes can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)

Comment: Thank you for your example of grabbing the credentials. Many of the other SDK objects just pull from the default application credentials, but the UrlSigner doesn't, which is irritating.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET client doesn't support signing URLs (it is an XML-only API), so you will need to either make a callout to a tool like [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#signing-gsutil) or generate an RSA signature internal to your application ([Signing and verifying signatures with RSA C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437288/signing-and-verifying-signatures-with-rsa-c-sharp))

Comment: You mean to say there is no alternate of a class Google_Signer_P12 which is there in php but not in dotnet?