# C# with Google Storage - Signed URL with customer encryption key

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I uploaded a file to Google storage bucket. Now, I generated a Signed Url of it (based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354609/how-to-sign-url-in-net-for-google-cloud-storage))

```
private static Uri SignUrl(Stream jsonCertificateStream, string bucketName, string objectName, TimeSpan expireAfter, string[] scopes, HttpMethod verb)
{
    string url;
    var urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountData(jsonCertificateStream);
    url = urlSigner.Sign(
                bucketName,
                objectName,
                expireAfter,
                verb);

    return new Uri(url);
}
```

I got back an URI which is working good with my browser. Up to here- everything working nice.

Now, I'm using Customer Encryption Key to encrypt my uploaded file. So, I removed the file and uploaded it again - now it's encrypted.

The problem is that now the `SignUrl()` method is not working any more.

When testing the outcome of the `SignUrl()` method with browser - I'm getting:

```
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceIsEncryptedWithCustomerEncryptionKey</Code>
    <Message>
        The resource is encrypted with a customer encryption key.
    </Message>
    <Details>
        The requested object is encrypted by a customer-supplied encryption key.
    </Details>
</Error>
```

I guess it's because my file is encrypted other key.

How to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys#headers)  , you need to add the following headers when using  Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys

```
+------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         Header name          | Value  |                                 Description                                  |
+------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| x-goog-encryption-algorithm  | string | The encryption algorithm to use. You must use the value AES256.              |
| x-goog-encryption-key        | string | An RFC 4648 Base64-encoded string of your AES-256 encryption key.            |
| x-goog-encryption-key-sha256 | string | An RFC 4648 Base64-encoded string of the SHA256 hash of your encryption key. |
+------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

also when using **urlSigner** you have to pass **x-goog-encryption-algorithm**

here a code example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;

namespace stackoverflow54387198
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // step 1 create customer encryption key
            var key = EncryptionKey.Generate().Base64Key;

            var encryptionKey = EncryptionKey.Create(Convert.FromBase64String(key));


            // step 2 get you service Acount cert for auth

            string serviceAcountCert = "stackoverflow54387198-xxxxxxxx.json";

            // step 3 get you service Acount cert for auth

            string bucketName = "stackoverflow_54387198_bucket";

            string localPath = "FileToUpload.txt";

            string objectName = null;


            // step 4 create a local text file to upload

            File.WriteAllText(localPath, "test");


            // step 5 Create Google Storage Client

            var storage = StorageClient.Create(
                GoogleCredential.FromJson(File.ReadAllText(serviceAcountCert)));


            // step 6 upload the file with the customer encryption key from step 1

            using (var f = File.OpenRead(localPath))

            {

                objectName = objectName ?? Path.GetFileName(localPath);

                storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, f,

                    new UploadObjectOptions()

                    {

                        EncryptionKey = encryptionKey

                    });

                Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {objectName}.");

            }


            // step 7 create a url


            // step 7.1 create add x-goog-encryption-algorithm hear 
            //to tell google you are using  customer encryption key

            var requestHeaders = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
            {
                {
                    "x-goog-encryption-algorithm", new [] { "AES256" }
                }
            };


            // step 7.2  set other parameters

            var expireAfter = TimeSpan.FromHours(30.0);

            var verb = HttpMethod.Get;


            // step 7.3  create a Url Signer

            var urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromServiceAccountPath(serviceAcountCert);


            // step 7.4  create a secure url
            var url = urlSigner.Sign(
                        bucketName,
                        objectName,
                        expireAfter,
                        verb,
                        requestHeaders);



            // step 8  use the Your Url


            // step 8.1 create HttpClient

            var client = new HttpClient();


            // step 8.1  add x-goog-encryption-algorithm header the same from step 7

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-goog-encryption-algorithm", "AES256");


            // step 8.2  add x-goog-encryption-key header with customer encryption key (Base64Hash)

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-goog-encryption-key", encryptionKey.Base64Key);


            // step 8.3  add x-goog-encryption-key header with customer encryption key (Base64Hash)

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-goog-encryption-key-sha256", encryptionKey.Base64Hash);

            // step 8.4  Download the file 
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // contents == "test"
                Console.WriteLine($"contents=>{contents}");

            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }


    }
}
```

also you can use postman to include the headers

[image]

### ref. 1

- [Generating Signed URLs with Your Own Program  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually)
- [Using Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/using-customer-supplied-keys#storage-upload-encrypted-object-csharp)
- [Creating Storage Buckets  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets#storage-create-bucket-csharp)
- [GCS Signed URL with Customer Supplied Encryption Key](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcs-signed-url-with-customer-supplied-encryption-key-c89740f31855)
- [dotnet-docs-samples/Storage.cs at master · GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Storage.cs)
- [c# - Adding headers when using httpClient.GetAsync - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync)
- [c# - Can't specify the 'async' modifier on the 'Main' method of a console app - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app)
- [How to put tables in Stack Overflow? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

### Extra

> Hi Mohamed, thanks for the comprehensive answer. According to your
>   answer, I understand that I cant just make a public signed URL that
>   will be used to download the file. I always must add additional
>   headers (x-goog-encryption-algorithm, x-goog-encryption-key, ...) in
>   order to get the file? It's isn't possible to include this data in the
>   URL field somehow?

#### To answer this i will use the flowing Questions :

- **skip to question 3 for solution**

#### Question 1

> It's isn't possible to include this data in the URL field somehow  ?

#### Answer 1

- I don't know

#### Why Answer 1 ?

- base on my **Logic**
- the google Storage API is a software written by a google programmer
- from the documentation they expect the encryption key to be in the header
- If you call the API without the key in header it will return an error message
- so maybe there is undocumented way , but I don't know

#### Question 2

What is the difference between HTTP parameters and HTTP headers usage

#### Answer 2

- see [What is the difference between HTTP parameters and HTTP headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40494772/4879683)

#### Question 3 :

How to hack around this ?

#### Answer 3

- if your are using this URL in a **web page** see : [javascript - How to set a header for a HTTP GET request, and trigger file download? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24505101/4879683)
- if your are using this URL in **mobile app** : you can download the file using the swift or java or the language of your app
- if your are using this URL in an **email** : you can create your own REST API using asp.net MVC or API which accept the  encryption key as parameter and then you act like a proxy between the google could and the client browser

#### Question 4 :

What is google storage Data Encryption Options

#### Answer 4

> Cloud Storage always [encrypts your data on the server
>   side](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/default-keys),
>   before it is written to disk, at no additional charge. Besides this
>   standard behavior, there are additional ways to encrypt your data when
>   using Cloud Storage. Below is a summary of the encryption options
>   available to you:
>
> - *Server-side encryption*: encryption that occurs after Cloud Storage receives your data, but before the data is written to disk and stored.
>
>   - [*Customer-supplied encryption keys*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-supplied-keys):
>       You can create and manage your own encryption keys for server-side
>       encryption, which act as an additional encryption layer on top of the
>       standard Cloud Storage encryption.
>   - [*Customer-managed encryption keys*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/customer-managed-keys):
>       You can generate and manage your encryption keys using Cloud Key
>       Management Service, which act as an additional encryption layer on top
>       of the standard Cloud Storage encryption.
> - [*Client-side encryption*](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/client-side-keys): encryption that occurs before data is sent to Cloud Storage. Such data
>     arrives at Cloud Storage already encrypted but also undergoes
>     server-side encryption.

- ref. : [Data Encryption Options  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/)

#### Question 5 :

Is better to use **Customer-Supplied Encryption Keys** ?

#### Answer 5 :

- it depends on you software scenario , but

  > Cloud Storage always encrypts your data on the server side, before it
  >   is written to disk, at no additional charge
- ref: [Data Encryption Options  |  Cloud Storage  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/encryption/)
- Maybe you don't need to encrypt your data using **Customer-supplied encryption keys** , because google encrypt **data at rest** by default, also  by the end of the day if you afraid of google spying on you (just my assumptionsas as a perfectionist myself ) ,it's not logical , because your are sending the encryption key to there servers when you request the file

### ref. 2 :

- [Mark It Down: convert rich text to Markdown](http://markitdown.medusis.com/)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for the comprehensive answer. According to your answer, I understand that I cant just make a public signed URL that will be used to download the file. I always must add additional headers (`x-goog-encryption-algorithm`, `x-goog-encryption-key`, ...) in order to get the file? It's isn't possible to include this data in the URL field somehow?

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever see my [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54510533/4879683) and skip to question 3 for solution