# How to create signature for my JWT?

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt, box

According to JWT (specifically, using the Box.com api), you need to

1. create your header and claims, base 64 url encode them, join them with a dot.
2. [You then need to take that and the secret key (a little confusion here, more on that in a second) and then encrypt them](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way/). For Box.com, it would be using RS256.
3. You then send that to the provider (again, in this case Box.com) and everything should be fine and dandy.

I have step 1 no problem.

Step 2 is a bit of a problem for me.

1. I assume I use my ... private key? Edit: Nope, private key is to decrypt.
2. Although far too many examples exist of doing this with HSA, I need to use RSA and the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT_stuff process has not been very forthcoming with helping. There are a couple other packages and libraries I could use that would be so easy if Box.com allowed for HSA256.

I've taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909044/how-to-sign-bytes-using-my-own-rsa-private-key-using-rs256-algorithm) and it hasn't been incredibly helpful.

So what do I need to do to complete step 2? In other words: How can I encrypt using RSA256 in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at [Box.com's developer page](https://box-content.readme.io/docs/sdks-and-tools) points to [Box .NET SDK by Box Mobile Team](https://github.com/box) on GitHub where there is a [BoxJWTAuth.cs](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2.JWTAuth/BoxJWTAuth.cs) with some code you can look at where they use RSA.

There is even a [Box.V2.Samples.JWTAuth/Program.cs](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2.Samples.JWTAuth/Program.cs) where they show how to use it.

On inspecting BoxJWTAuth I saw this snippet of code

```
private string ConstructJWTAssertion(string sub, string boxSubType)
{
    byte[] randomNumber = new byte[64];
    using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
    }

    var claims = new List<Claim>{
        new Claim("sub", sub),
        new Claim("box_sub_type", boxSubType),
        new Claim("jti", Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber)),
    };

    var payload = new JwtPayload(this.boxConfig.ClientId, AUTH_URL, claims, null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30));

    var header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials: this.credentials);
    if (this.boxConfig.JWTPublicKeyId != null)
        header.Add("kid", this.boxConfig.JWTPublicKeyId);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    string assertion = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    return assertion;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does. I have a hard time navigating through their sdk because several of the projects won't load because I'm not on Windows 8/8.1. That makes it more difficult than it needs to be to implement their objects and track through the code because, hey, I can't run it. But seeing this tells me that I was on the right track with what I ended up trying to do. And this gives me the framework that I was missing. Thumbs up, man! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. glad to help.