# Cannot Load private key from a RSA PRIVATE KEY file in C#

Tags: c#, openssl, rsa, x509certificate2

I want to sign some data with `RSA.SignHash()`.
I've created a RSA private key file via the following command in Linux OpenSSL.

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 1024
```

But when I want to load this key by an object of `X509Certificate2`, get the "Cannot find the requested object." exception.
Here is my code:

```
string keyFilePath = @"C:\Keys\private_key.pem";
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath);
```

I've used the `Chilkat` library and everything works fine, But doesn't `Microsoft` have any walk-though to approach it without any third-party tools?
Here is my pem file content:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Its the pem format that is the issue, see: [how to get private key from PEM file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400500/how-to-get-private-key-from-pem-file)

Comment: Dear @AlexK. and Simone Cifani, I've tried the other article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400500/how-to-get-private-key-from-pem-file). And same exception. I do not have any Certificate. I have a private key.

Comment: Just stating the obvious: a key is not a certificate. It does not make sense to try to load a private key into a certificate object.

Comment: Dear @jww please direct me how to sign with just a private key.

Comment: [Signing and verifying signatures with RSA C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8437288/608639), [how to sign bytes using my own rsa private key using rs256 algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25909044/608639), [Signing data with private key in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31828420/608639), [How can I sign a file using RSA and SHA256 with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7444586/608639), [Signing a string with RSA private key on .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3169829/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no friendly way to do it without third-party tools. If you only have private key then IMHO `new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath)` does not make sense.

What you could do is implement (or use a library) to parse the private key. Then encode parsed private key parameters to a xml structure that can be imported using [RSA.FromXmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.fromxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx).